# Can't stringify objects over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, properties, tostring

I've a working WCF service and while writing a test for it, I added the following lines.

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
Thing thing = client.GetThing();
System.WriteLine(thing.SomeProperty);
```

The above works just as supposed to. Then, I was trying to perform stringification and each of the following failed in a number of ways. The first fail is on these calls.

```
System.WriteLine(thing);
System.WriteLine("" + thing);
System.WriteLine(thing.ToString());
```

It only shows the name of the class, although I've added custom *ToString* method to *Thing* class. I haven't exposed the custom *ToString* explicitly but it's included in the classes created for me by VS automatically, so I'm assuming that it's exposed by the parent class (i.e. *Object*).

```
public class Thing
{
  public String SomeProperty { ... }
  public override String ToString() { ... }
  //public new String ToString() { ... }
  //public String ToString() { ... }
}
```

**What am I missing here?**

Then, I though that I could implement a new property, that returns the stringification instead. However, the property, although visible when I obtain the instance of *Thing*, is *null*.

```
public Stringification { get { return SomeProperty + "!"; } set { } }
//public ToString { get { return SomeProperty + "!"; } set { } }
```

**Why isn't it providing me with the actual value of the property?**

Comment: Readh, may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181039/wcf-datacontract-tostring-function

Comment: @wudzik Yes, partly it help. I kind of suspected that I might be forced to explicitly add contract for my own *ToString* method. However, not wanting to do that, I tested the property (and *String* properties are included automatically). Still, I get *null* on it and can't see why.